# How to access the REST api with the browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest

All, Forgive me this newbie question. I can get the `REST` result which shows xml format with the browser (ie , chrome ) from `Share Point 2013 online trial`.

[image]

But got non-xml format from `Share Point 2013 server` of the intranet. Did I miss something ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using in Sharepoint 2013 server?

Comment: Windows server 2012 R2 IE11.

Comment: I knew the problem. It is because of the setting of browser.

Comment: try with chrome or firefox and check if same issue occurs.

Comment: Please read http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=internet-explorer-cannot-display-this-feed

Comment: But I didn't found this option/setting in the FF.

Comment: so you problem is only with FF?

Comment: Yes. But I can use rest client add-on to send rest call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises as the response come as atom feed and IE by default set to read atom feed and present it in a better format. Go to IE settings - Internet Options -> Content -> Feed and Web Slices -> Settings and uncheck "Turn on feed reading view".